# RegEx: date/time (sub)string

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate, with a RegEx, a user input to a date/time field in the following format: `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm`. Since a user would type this one character at a time, the RegEx also needs to allow for all the substrings (e.g., `yyyy-mm`, `yyyy-mm-dd H`, etc.).

For example, the following date `2022-01-29 11:59` or any substring of it, such as (empty string), `202`, `2022-01-`, `2022-01-29`, etc. should match.
Strings like `2022-13`, `222-` or `2024-01-01 23:111` should not match.

I am trying something like,

```
[0-9]{4}?-?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-?(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])? ?(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])?:?[0-5]?[0-9]?$
```

making every character optional, but it does not work since it can just skip parts of the string, e.g. `2022-29` returns match...

Comment: do you need it to only match the full date-time? is your first table what you *want*? what isn't working?

Comment: @vetsin, either the full string or its substring... Yes, the first table is what I want.

Comment: Are you sure that regex is the right tool for the job?

Comment: @knittl, not at all, but just curious how would it work with RegEx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It becomes a bit convoluted if you want to match number ranges properly as you type. Here is a regex solution with test cases that has many nested groups (to allow partial input) and validates the ranges of month, day, hours, and minutes:

```js
const regex = /^([0-9]{0,3}|[0-9]{4}(-([01]|(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(-([0-3]|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])( ([0-2]|([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])(:([0-5]|([0-4][0-9]|5[0-9]))?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)$/;

[
  '',
  '2',
  '20',
  '202',
  '2022',
  '2022-',
  '2022-0',
  '2022-01',
  '2022-01-',
  '2022-01-2',
  '2022-01-29',
  '2022-01-29 ',
  '2022-01-29 1',
  '2022-01-29 11',
  '2022-01-29 11:',
  '2022-01-29 11:5',
  '2022-01-29 11:59',
  '202-01',
  '2022-1-1',
  '2022-13',
  '2022-01-32',
  '2024-01-01 24',
  '2024-01-01 01:60',
  '2024-01-01 23:111'
].forEach(str => console.log(str, '=>', regex.test(str)));
```

Output:

```
 => true
2 => true
20 => true
202 => true
2022 => true
2022- => true
2022-0 => true
2022-01 => true
2022-01- => true
2022-01-2 => true
2022-01-29 => true
2022-01-29  => true
2022-01-29 1 => true
2022-01-29 11 => true
2022-01-29 11: => true
2022-01-29 11:5 => true
2022-01-29 11:59 => true
202-01 => false
2022-1-1 => false
2022-13 => false
2022-01-32 => false
2024-01-01 24 => false
2024-01-01 01:60 => false
2024-01-01 23:111 => false
```

Hierarchy of regex:

- `^(` -- start of string & group

  - `[0-9]{0,3}` -- 0 to 3 digits for partial year
- `|` -- logical or

  - `[0-9]{4}` --
  - `(` --

    - `-` -- dash
    - `(` --

      - `[01]` -- one digit of month
    - `|` -- logical or

      - `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])` -- two digits of month
      - `(` --

        - `-` -- dash
        - `(` --

          - `[0-3]` -- one digit of day
        - `|` -- logical or

          - `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` -- two digits of day
          - `(` --

            - -- space
            - `(` --

              - `[0-2]` -- one digit of hours
            - `|` -- logical or

              - `([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])` -- two digits of hours
              - `(` --

                - `:` -- colon
                - `(` --

                  - `[0-5]` -- one digit of minutes
                - `|` -- logical or

                  - `([0-4][0-9]|5[0-9])` -- two digits of minutes
                - `)?` --
              - `)?` --
            - `)?` --
          - `)?` --
        - `)?` --
      - `)?` --
    - `)?` --
  - `)?` --
- `)$` -- end of string and group

Learn more about regex: https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex